# Search list between specific index in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, search

I need to create a function that will search for a list-item between specific indexes.

I want to have a start and stop index for the list, I want to find the position of the item in the list.

For example:

```
def find(list, word, start=0, stop=-1):
    print("In function find()")

    for item in list:
        if item == word:
            return list[start:stop].index(word)

n_list = ['one', 'five', 'three', 'eight', 'five', 'six', 'eight']
print(find(n_list, "eight", start=4, stop=7 ))
```

This code will return "2", because the word "eight" is in the index position of 2 in list[4:7].

My question: How can I change this code so that it returns "6"? If I remove the [4:7], it's giving me "3" because the word "eight" is also in the [3] position.

Edit: forgot to say thank you!

Comment: Do you always want to get the last index of your word?

Comment: the function returns "2" because you are calling index on `list[start:stop]` which is itself a list

Answer (score 2):

Can't you simply add start?

```
def find(list, word, start=0, stop=-1):
print("In function find()")

for item in list:
    if item == word:
        return start + list[start:stop].index(word)
```

Comment: Note: This will fail if `word` is in the list but outside of the slice.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that the range characterized by `start` and `stop` can be trusted you can make it into a one-liner:

```
n_list[start:stop].index(word)+start
```

Comment: This will throw a `ValueError` if the element is not in the slice, so you might want to wrap this into `try/except`. Otherwise fine.

Comment: @tobias_k How about `if stop > len(list): return` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop is not needed:

```
def find(list, word, start=0, stop=-1)
    '''Find word in list[start:stop]'''
    try:
       return start + list[start:stop].index(word)
    Except ValueError:
       raise ValueError("%s was not found between indices %s and %s"%(word, start, stop))
```